# Does "import *" prevent tree-shaking with Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, tree-shaking

I've seen https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade which recommends moving to the Firebase Modular SDK. The recommended way to use it seems to be:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth"
import { getDatabase, ref, set, update, get, push, serverTimestamp } from "firebase/database"
```

which works fine and is nicely tree-shakeable. But it creates lots of free functions with common names like `set` and `get` and `update` which impedes readability and can cause naming conflicts.

My question is whether it is OK to instead do:

```js
import * as RTDB from "firebase/database"
```

and similarly for the others, and then use `RTDB.update` etc. Will that still be tree-shaken in all modern bundlers?

Comment: You can alias: `import { set as dbSet, get as dbGet, update as dbUpdate }`

Comment: The answer to your question is really dependent on how your bundler works.

Comment: @DougStevenson that's what I was afraid of. If I go the "import *" route and someone uses a different bundler they might not get tree-shook.

Comment: Someone closed the question, which I understand, but none of the provided references is authoritative. Some say it's OK to use "import *" and some say definitely don't. I guess the safest thing is to avoid it; that's what I'll do.

Comment: You can measure for yourself the effect of your bundler by comparing the results either way and decide based on that.